# Write a good test for a function that implicitly takes options from a parameter file

Tags: python, python-unittest

I have a function that looks like this in principle:

```
def myfunction(parameter):
    methodx = config['methodx']

    if methodx == 'method_a':
        something = apply_methoda_to_parameter
    if methodx == 'method_b':
        something = apply_methodb_to_parameter
    return something
```

The `config['methodx']` comes from an external configuration file.
What is the nicest way to write a test function that covers both cases `method_a` and `method_b`?
Do I have to make `methodx` a keyword to test it?

Comment: If that's the only config it uses, why not? Or use mock to patch out the whole config dictionary.

Comment: Why does it have to be the only config? You mean for readability reasons?

Comment: It doesn't have to be, maybe you're actually using lots of config items in that function. My point is *if it's only using one*, pass that one in. If it's using several, maybe pass the whole config in. Relying on global state is a code smell; as you're seeing, it's making the code harder to test.

Comment: Now I've got it....it's indeed using only one and the `config` dictionary is quite large, so think I'll make it a keyword. If you want you can also suggest this as an answer, from your comment I gues there might not come along so many other answers...